# Problem with making website mobile using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a website. the link of the website is here

http://afaanimpex.com.pk/

The website is working perfectly on desktop but for the mobile, you have to first scroll right toward the top right corner to make the navbar menu appear and once it appears there is white space in right till the end. I tried hard but can't find where I am doing wrong. I tried using all CSS tricks but nothing seems to be working 
Here is some code where I guess the problem lies but I am not sure

```
.masthead
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:35rem;
    padding:15rem 0;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(22,22,22,.3)),color-stop(75%,rgba(22,22,22,.7)),to(#161616)),url(../img/bg-masthead.jpg);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(22,22,22,.3) 0,rgba(22,22,22,.7) 75%,#161616 100%),url(../img/bg-masthead.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Your website has a horizontal scrollbar. You need to remove it first

Comment: how to remove it @JoykalInfotech

Comment: You need to remove inline css from (.form-inline .form-control) input box and textarea in your contact section

Comment: margin-right from inline css

Comment: @Umer pls make sure you do not have any <br> and <p> tags in form. Also use class form-group to wrap form-controls.

Comment: @Umer you have to vote at least if one of the answers helped you. That's how a community works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

margin-left:375px is creating issue for you

https://www.screencast.com/t/nogHWkxA0aev

check these screenshot
https://www.screencast.com/t/41dbRDXE

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add this line inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And in this `<div>`

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0 text-center text-white-50" style="margin-left: 375px;margin-top: 100px;">
          Copyright © Afaan Impex Pvt. Limited
     </div>
```

remove the inline style with the margins you have added and instead of putting margin in a `col-md-4` class you can replace with this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-center text-white-50" style="margin-top: 100px;">
          Copyright © Afaan Impex Pvt. Limited
     </div>
```

remember always use the grid system of boostrap with aligning the items.

Comment: Yes this was great help. however i am still having issues with the about-section background styling. where the background fixed property is causing issues in iphone. can you help me in this regard. what styling should i use to prevent it